# can't override appsettings.json settings with environment variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I can't override the settings of my `appsettings.json` file with environment variables.

`appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "AppSettings": {
    "LocalUpdatesDir": "<some path>",
    "BinaryDeltaCount": 5,
    "BinaryDeltaFilenameTemplate": "<template>",
    "Azure": {
      "User": "user here",
      "Password": "password here"
    }
  },
}
```

Main:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var webHost = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;
            config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                  .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    webHost.Run();
}
```

**Environment variables:**

[image]

> **Update 1:**

Here I can see, that all my providers are registered:

[image]

What's really strange: In the environments variable list, there are about 80 entries in it. My two new ones are missing, BUT there are 2 environment variables in it, which I created a few hours ago and deleted right away. WHERE THE HECK ARE THEY COMING FROM?!

> **Update 2:**

I restarted my computer and now I see my Environment variable in the list, but it doesn't override the value in `appsettings.json`?

Comment: Why do you have a single underscore `_` in your environment variable to separate everything and then two underscores `__` to separate Azure and User/Password?

Comment: read it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931613/how-to-correctly-store-connection-strings-in-environment-variables-for-retrieval

Im working on windows and not linux, but I just wanted to give it a shot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove the `ASPNETCORE_` prefix from your env variables or add it as a parameter to `AddEnvironmentVariables`, there's no prefix by default.

Edit: Try enumerating the config to see if the keys are lining up as you'd expect.

```
private static void ShowConfig(IConfiguration config)
{
    foreach (var pair in config.GetChildren())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Path} - {pair.Value}");
        ShowConfig(pair);
    }
}
```

Comment: OP could also have their (I'm guessing, dev specific) variables stored in an `appsettings.developement.json` or in User Secrets

Comment: @JamieTaylor Thanks for the hint! I'm already using `appsettings.developement.json` for development. My question was more regarding production environment.

Comment: @Tratcher Thx, but it's still not working. Please have a look at the update in my original post.

Comment: @Tratcher Thanks for the tip. I had 2 things to do: 1) Restarting my computer after changing the environment variables. 2) Changing the environment variables to this syntax 'AppSettings:Azure:User'

Comment: Hey @roli09, for me restarting the VS was enough, it seems that VS stores the enviroment variables on startup, anyway thank you guys for helped me sorting this out...

Comment: Saving env variable in the format of 'AppSettings:Azure:User' did the trick. Not just restarting VS

Answer (score 9):

I was on the same boat as you and I figured out a few things that might help you and everybody else having the same headache.

First of all, as mentioned on the other answer, you do not need any prefix. So both ASPNETCORE_ and AppSettings are unnecessary, unless you pass them as prefix into AddEnvironmentVariables(). So simply go azure:password.

Secondly you do not necessarily need double underscore to make an env var that maps nested appsettings value. Just go with a single colon.

Example:

This one in appsettings:

```
"azure": {
  "password": "my.weak.azure.password"
}
```

can be overridden by this environment variable:

[image]

Lastly, the values added to Environment Variables on Windows are apparently cached by Visual Studio or its background processes like Console Window Host. Closing and reopening Visual Studio would get you the new values. That is why you noticed seeing them after restarting your machine.

[image]

Comment: ```:``` is not supported on all platforms for example in ```bash``` (f.e.: docker environment)

Comment: Awesome, this is very easy to use in a `docker-compose.yml`, backed by a `.env`!
For example, we can define 
```yml
environment:
  MYPREFIX_DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString: mongodb://$DB_USER:$DB_PASS@mongo:27017/
``` and the string is interpolated with the secrets from the `.env` file. Your answer was a huge help! Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

The order you call the `.Add()` functions is important.  If you want to overwrite the values from appsettings.json then this

```
builder.Configuration
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true, true);
```

Will not overwrite the values from Json, it will do the opposite.

```
builder.Configuration
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env}.json", true, true)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddUserSecrets(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

This will overwrite the values from the Json with Environment variables.

Comment: There is default behavior and priorities to work with environment variables and configurations.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#default-application-configuration-sources

Answer (score 4):

As [Tratcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48168720/11473934) mentioned the prefix `ASPNETCORE_` is not needed. Below is the description how to override appsettings with environment variables in general.

### Naming of environment variables for appsettings

There is kind of a **naming convention in the environment variables** for nested appsettings to env vars, [see naming of environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#naming-of-environment-variables-1).
Each element in the hierarchy is separated by a double underscore (even array indices). `__` works on all platforms, the other seperators won't.

Comment: The section link change to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#naming-of-environment-variables-1

Comment: Changed it, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a new ASP.NET Core Web App with .NET 5 from Visual Studio your `Program.cs` will look like this:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

Looking at `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` we can see the following comment:

> load app Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration from
> environment variables

[image]

This means that if you use a default template overrides will work.

If you want to prefix with `ASPNETCORE_` or `DOTNET_` it will work by default as well.

If you want to use a custom prefix you can do that like this:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables("ASPNETCORECUSTOM_");
        });
```

If you want to override `Microsoft` with `Error` below the override should look like this: Logging:LogLevel:Microsoft - Error

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

[image]

Another way to override Configuration is using `ConfigurationInjection` and hosting startup where you can specify whether you want the hosting startup's configuration to take precedence or the app's configuration to take precedence:

```
public class ConfigurationInjection : IHostingStartup
{
    public void Configure(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> dict;

        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
        {
            dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"ConfigurationKey1", 
                    "From IHostingStartup: Higher priority " +
                    "than the app's configuration."},
            };

            config.AddInMemoryCollection(dict);
        });

        dict = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"ConfigurationKey2", 
                "From IHostingStartup: Lower priority " +
                "than the app's configuration."},
        };

        var builtConfig = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddInMemoryCollection(dict)
            .Build();

        builder.UseConfiguration(builtConfig);
    }
}
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/platform-specific-configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configuration-provided-by-the-hosting-startup

Answer (score 0):

I have spend some time with trying to use environment variables to override our config, as well. For me on windows in our test project it works only if:

- AddEnvironmentVariables must be after the AddJsonFile
- AddEnvironmentVariables must use prefix, e .g. c.AddEnvironmentVariables("Test_");
- the separator must be ':', e.g. "Test_AppSettings:ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"

Our config looks like this:

```
{ 
  AppSettings: {
   ConnectionStrings: {
      DefaultConnection: "something"
   }
  }
}
```

Here is complete example:

```
            using var host = await new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(c =>
            {
                // System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Test_AppSettings_ConnectionStrings_DefaultConnection", "X"); // DOES NOT WORK
                // System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("AppSettings_ConnectionStrings_DefaultConnection", "X"); // DOES NOT WORK
                System.Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Test_AppSettings:ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection", "X");

                var d = ... directory

                c.AddJsonFile(Path.Combine(d, "appsettings.json"));

                //c.AddEnvironmentVariables(); // DOES NOT WORK
                c.AddEnvironmentVariables("Test_");

            })
```

Answer (score 0):

Three steps we need to follow here,

1. Create ConfigurationBuilder,

> ```
> var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
> ```

2. Add 2 nuget packages,

   > Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json
3. Create configs with prefix key "Jai_"

`.AddEnvironmentVariables("Jai_");`

app setting has key **"consumer"**
in your environment you need to set with prefix **"Jai_consumer"**

[image]