# How to add environment variables to app.json file

Tags: json, react-native, expo

I have an `app.json` file in my `Expo` project. In this file I have two API keys (labeled API_KEY below) that I'd like to hide via environment variables.

How can I go about using environment variables instead of hard coding the API keys?

**app.json**

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Closeout",
    "slug": "Closeout",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "privacy": "hidden",
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/notification-icon.png",
      "color": "#000000",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
      "buildNumber": "2",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": "API_KEY"
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#000"
      },
      "versionCode": 5,
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": "API_KEY"
        }
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: here you'll find an explanaition on this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168369/cant-override-appsettings-json-settings-with-environment-variables/67719140#67719140

Comment: Did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score 8):

I'm guessing you may have figured out a solution or tried something else by now. However, here is a solution to this issue, I hope it helps anyone facing the same challenge. This is from a typescript environment I'm implementing.

Create an app.config.ts file that overrides the content of the app.json file

```
import { ExpoConfig, ConfigContext } from '@expo/config';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';

// initialize dotenv
dotenv.config();

export default ({ config }: ConfigContext): ExpoConfig => ({
  ...config,
  slug: 'my-app',
  name: 'My App',
  ios: {
    supportsTablet: true,
    bundleIdentifier: 'com.croon',
    config: {
      googleMapsApiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY,
    },
  },
  android: {
    adaptiveIcon: {
      foregroundImage: './assets/adaptive-icon.png',
      backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
    },
    package: 'com.croon',
    config: {
      googleMaps: {
        apiKey: process.env.GOOGLE_CLOUD_API_KEY,
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Then you could leave the API entry blank on the app.json file.

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "Closeout",
    "slug": "Closeout",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "privacy": "hidden",
    "notification": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/notification-icon.png",
      "color": "#000000",
      "iosDisplayInForeground": true
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": ["**/*"],
    "ios": {
      "icon": "./assets/images/icon.png",
      "buildNumber": "2",
      "config": {
        "googleMapsApiKey": ""
      }
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/images/icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#000"
      },
      "versionCode": 5,
      "useNextNotificationsApi": true,
      "config": {
        "googleMaps": {
          "apiKey": ""
        }
      },
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    }
  }
}
```

Remember to install the required dependencies

Cheers!