# How are environmental variables for ASP.NET CORE injected in the application (ASPNETCORE_*)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, environment-variables

When I start Asp.Net Core application in Visual studio, it runs the `dotnet.exe` file with my dll as a parameter.

Additionally I see that application has access to a lot of different environmental variables that are not available in ordinary console application, e.g. `ASPNETCORE_CONTENTROOT`. This one does some magic to allow `appsettings.json` files to be read directly from the project directory rather than `bin/debug`. I wanted to achieve the same in my console application to avoid copying file to the `bin/debug` folder, but I could not figure out what injects those variables.

So the question is really how do these environmental variables appear in the Asp.Net application?

I suspect that WebHost or some core libraries do that, but could not find any proof of that or any code to figure out how is the source directory being read.

P.S. I am not trying to find out how to make environmental variables available via configuration (like e.g. AddEnvironmentalVariables), but how do they get to be Environmental variables in the process itself in the first place (so that they later can be read by config).

I am interested in this for 2 reasons: to figure out how `ASPNETCORE_CONTENTROOT` is set to do the same for console application and out of curiosity :)

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44933016/455493) may help :P Not completely related to the question, but the answer kinda tells you where it comes from. They come in via the `AddEnvironmentVariables()` configuration source, the prefix `ASPNETCORE_*` can be overridden there)

Comment: In the newer ASP.NET Core templates its less obvious as its hidden behind `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` call, which registers all the default configuration sources (json,environment specific, environment, commandline etc). See [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L161-L183)

Comment: @Tseng I am trying to figure out where are they injected in the executable itself, not in the configuration. AddEnvironmentalVariables just allows them to be read in config. I will clarify the question, it seems it's not precise enough and confusing.

Comment: There is a fallback, but it is not empty, so the fallback is not used, at least in my case. I have checked in the Process Explorer and the environmental variable points to the Project Source, not the same folder as CurrentDirectory. That is 3 levels up from CurrentDirectory

Comment: Here is the link to where it is read: [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Hosting/Hosting/src/Internal/WebHostOptions.cs#L32), but where it is set remains a mistery to me :)

Comment: My suspicion right now is that it's handled by the ANCM - just seeing if I can find out more... The environment variables only seem to be set when using the ANCM in `OutOfProcess` mode.

Comment: Looks like you are right and at least ASPNETCORE_TOKEN is set there (according to documentation), though same thing works when I do run "commandName": "Project" as well. Not sure how it is handled, it used to run pure Kestrel before, but is seems it is not so pure anymore and runs under VSIISExeLauncher.exe

Comment: The [CreateDefaultBuilder](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/3c09d644cccdb21801f7a79e1188a1a1212de5d9/src/DefaultBuilder/src/WebHost.cs#L152-L155) sets a default value if the value obtained from the configuration is empty. Was it that you were looking for? As for the HOW it reads it? [EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/blob/master/src/Configuration/Config.EnvironmentVariables/src/EnvironmentVariablesConfigurationProvider.cs#L46)

Comment: @Tseng I was trying to understand how environmental variables appear in the process itself. It is doing something if it's empty, but it is not empty, variables are set some place in the process, so I was trying to figure out where, but it seems that Kirk Larkin is correct and it is set by some proxy process that is run on top of Kestrel.

Comment: But the final and big question is: Why?! XD You can use the Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.* packages in Console application, even when you don't use ASP.NET Core. So all you need is to build it yourself: var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("my.json", optional: false).AddCommandLine(args).AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "MYPREFIX_").Build();` in your Program.cs or even better: Use the new [Generic Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to bootstrap a (long running) console application

Comment: Well, when its hosted in IIS the ANCM does a lot, but I never digged into it tbh

Comment: Well, I just tried to understand how it read "my.json" file not from the bin folder but the source folder initially, which is quite useful for development. I have read suggestions to do "Copy Always" on the file e.g., but that has a drawback that editing just file won't really copy it. So it was best to have a correct reference to the source folder. I have done it now by just pointing manually to the correct folder in development environment, so why is just curiosity to be honest :)

Comment: @Tseng What about this Generic Host? I have seen that this is a new thing in the latest .Net Core but thought it's better to do bare bones myself, since it comes from some asp.net source. So I was not sure it is really decoupled fully from Asp.Net that I don't need in a console. Can't see too much benefits in using it apart from a bit less config to write?

Comment: Generic Host is a more generic version of bootstrapping applications which are not ASP.NET Core (ASP.NET Core used and still use WebHost for bootstrapping, but in future it will be switched to a generic host. You can use it to configure Dependency Injection and start one (or multiple) hosts within the same executable, which are basically separate from each other (i.e. bootstrapping ASP.NET Core and a background running host like a background job, i.e. some kind of scheduler or queue based task which is not tied to request life time) aka Hosted Services.

Comment: The advantage is you get the same bootstrapping experience as ASP.NET Core for all your other server applications, including the Console Life time (which allows you to terminate the application with Ctrl+C). I used it to bootstrap a game server I am toying around for example. You can start multiple hosts with it (who all listen on different ports, i.e. login server, chat server, game server, assets server) all from the same process. This includes setting of the content root `builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());`(which will be your project folder when run from Visual Studio)

Comment: That's why the "F5 Experience" in Visual Studio just works (no Views in MVC applications are copied to the bin/Debug folders) and why you can have the "Edit and Refresh browser" experience on MVC Views w/o restarting the application, cause your project is the content root. This is also true for `dotnet run` which runs also on project,but `dotnet publish` generates output views since you don't start it with `dotnet run` but `dotnet ./MyApplication.dll`

Comment: @Tseng My application just a one time job that we'll run on schedule once a day, so it's probably not worth adding Generic Host there? Probably the overhead is minimal anyway and we should use it for convenience :) Though I doubt that content root will be magically set as it is done for asp.net so this part we'll have to do anyway :)

Comment: @Tseng, anyway thanks a lot for help and pointers :)