# How to override ASP.NET Core connection string with Dockerfile

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker

I'm trying to override the following connection string which is located inside `appsettings.json` on an ASP.NET Core API.

```json
"ConnectionStrings": {
  "Connection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=NetCoreSample;User Id=sa;Password=sa;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  },
```

To achieve so I added `AddEnvironmentVariables()` to my `HostBuilder`:

```cs
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        })
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

And my `Dockerfile` is as follows:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build-env

WORKDIR /src
COPY . ./

ENV CONNECTIONSTRINGS__CONNECTION="Server=sql-server;Database=NetCoreSample;User Id=sa;Password=sa@a2020;MultipleActiveResultSets=true" 

WORKDIR /src/Api
RUN dotnet restore 
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out --no-restore

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

COPY --from=build-env /src/Api/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api.dll"]

EXPOSE 80
```

Note that my API and SQLServer are being built on `docker-compose`.

Yet when I try to run the image, my API throws this error, related to the connection string.

```
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
```

If I override the connection string manually on the `.json` file it works just fine. So It's clear to me that my `ConnectionString` is not being properly overridden.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You can have the build script to write proper connection string to settings file while building the application and creating the package.

Comment: Why you don't want add different `appsettings.json` files for every environment?

Comment: Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931613/how-to-correctly-store-connection-strings-in-environment-variables-for-retrieval

Comment: @SergeyNazarov actually I think a new `appsettings.json` would be a better idea. But them how can I change my environment on my `Dockerfile`?

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt `docker run -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=docker` where docker environment name. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables

Comment: @SergeyNazarov Okay, I think it's better to use it directly on my `Dockerfile` as I'm using `docker-compose`, so I added `ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT="Docker"`, and I set a `Console.WriteLine(env.EnvironmentName);`  on my `Startup.cs`. Yet when I run my container it stills displays `Production` as the current environment. What am I missing here?

Comment: @RogerioSchmitt I think you set env for docker build. Generally It's not good idea to hardcode any env variables at dockerfile, better set them when run container. You can [set environment variable at docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/).

Comment: @SergeyNazarov That did the trick, thanks a lot. If you want to submit something in those lines as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use different `appsetings.json` files for every environment. See samples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44931613/how-to-correctly-store-connection-strings-in-environment-variables-for-retrieval).

Then you can run your container with required environment name using `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`.
For container use [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables):

```
docker run -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=environment_name ...
```

You can see how to set env variables for compose [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#env-environment-variables).